# GtkIconView Right Click Activate

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, pygtk

I'm building an application using GTK 3+ with Python, and I'm having trouble with `GtkIconView`. When there are icons in the view, I would like to be able to left and right click on the icon. A single left click works correctly, but I'm having trouble selecting on right click.

Right click is supposed to show a popup menu. I had a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/144311/how-to-make-a-gtk-iconview-react-to-single-click-instead-of-double-click

It was suggested that I work with a `button_press_event` then move on from there.
Here is my code with regards to the above suggestion:

```
def on_button_press_event(self, widget, event):
    if event.type == Gdk.EventType.BUTTON_PRESS:
        choice = util.get_selection(.....)
        #get the text of the selected icon

        if event.button == 3:
            print("Right CLick")
            print(choice)
        elif event.button == 1:
            print("LEFT CLICK")
            print(choice)
```

At this stage when I click on the icon, both left and right click do not select the icon thereby choice becomes `[]`. Only double clicking selects the icon.

Is there a way to select the icon with a single click regardless on the button?

I've added `GtkIconView.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)` but that does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using the `button_press_event`.

```
 if event.type == Gdk.EventType.BUTTON_PRESS:
    path = GtkIconView.get_path_at_pos(event.x, event.y)
    if path != None:
        GtkIconView.select_path(path)
        choice = util.get_selection(GtkIconView,GtkListStore)
        if event.button == 3:
            # popup on right click
        elif event.button == 1:
            self.on_GtkIconView_activated(widget,choice)
```

To receive any signal from a mouse click you have to add

```
GtkIconView.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
```

So any mouse button click on the icon will result in the text of the icon being displayed, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, is setting the `activate-on-single-click` property not sufficient enough? I don't think this was mentioned anywhere in the question you linked.

Anyway, you need to return the Python equivalent of `GDK_EVENT_PROPAGATE` (whatever that is) from your GDK events (like `button-press-event`), otherwise other event handlers (like the ones that are part of GtkIconView itself) won't run. I assume you're hitting undefined behavior because you aren't returning anything explicitly and in this case the undefined behavior is "return the equivalent of `GDK_EVENT_STOP`".